# ¿Por qué no salen datos en mi consola de H2?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, spring-boot, maven, h2

Configuré una base de datos en memoria para mi proyecto de spring-boot con maven de la siguiente manera

### pom.xml

```
<!-- Temporal dependency to test H2 database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--orm-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

### application.properties

```
#Temporal H2 DB to test
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Al abrir el navegador en

```
http://localhost:8080/h2-console
```

me sale lo siguiente

[image: configuración por defecto de conexion a H2]

El problema es que la base de datos sale vacía.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se necesita alguna otra configuración para consultar la base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Para conectarte a la base de datos en memoria de tu aplicación spring boot debes usar la siguiente URL de JDBC:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Como verás con ello las tablas ya aparecerán

[image: consola web de H2 con las tablas cargadas de la aplicación que está corriendo]